# Trace directory not defined error in MS Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

I'm getting the following event log entry when I turn on tracing in CRM using the CRM Diagnostics Tool. Any ideas why it's not picking up the correct directory to place the files?

> ```
> CrmTrace encountered a failure creating or opening the file named
> ```
>
> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics
>   CRM\Trace\CRM-SERVER-CrmAsyncService-bin-20091106-1.log`.
>   (Reporting Process:CrmAsyncService,
>   AppDomain:C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM\Server\bin)

Answer (score 1):

- Why are you running the trace, what problem are you troubleshooting?
- Do you have write access to that Trace directory?
- Can you click the "Create File" button and post that information?
- Have you enabled "DevErrors"?

Comment: - I'm troubleshooting the lack of outgoing emails via the email router. Incoming emails to a queue work fine but no outgoing ones work. I'm trying to get the trace working as some googling indicates that useful information might be hiding there!

I've got it working though - I had to create the Trace directory and then give write access to it for the account that was running the CRM IIS process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions should be given to the user running the Asynchronous service, that is not the same as the IIS Application Pool.

Check the Account that is running the Async Service, and the Email router. Both accounts should have access to the directory described in the error in the Event Viewer (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Trace)

After that you should have access to the logs.